# magento1.9 soap api to get invoice information

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v1

I wants to get the invoice information based on order id in magento 1.9

using soap api.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this Example

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

    $notInvoicedOrderId  = '100000003';

    // Create new invoice
    $newInvoiceId = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order_invoice.create', array($notInvoicedOrderId, array(), 'Invoice Created', true, true));

    // View new invoice
    $invoice = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order_invoice.info', $newInvoiceId);

    var_dump($invoice);

    // Add Comment
    $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order_invoice.addComment', array($newInvoiceId, 'Invoice comment, some text', true, false));

    // View invoice with new comment
    $invoice = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order_invoice.info', $newInvoiceId);

    var_dump($invoice);

    $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order_invoice.capture', $newInvoiceId);

    // View captured invoice
    $invoice = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order_invoice.info', $newInvoiceId);
    var_dump($invoice);
```

Comment: Hi @sania thanks for your answer but i wants get all ready created invoices information based on order id

Answer (score 0):

Request Example SOAP V1

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentication,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'sales_order_invoice.info', '200000006');
var_dump($result);

// If you don't need the session anymore
//$client->endSession($session);
```

For More detail follow magento doc :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrderInvoice/sales_order_invoice.info.html

Comment: The above link is worked for passing increment id only not order id